# Page layouts of elements

Tags: html

I'm not very expert in html, but i would like to know where it is possible to understand if an item is close to another element. For instance a `div` to another `div` or if a table is adjacent to an image or an another table.

Comment: I would like to extract some informations about a web page as a section close to another section, a table close to another table ect. I don't work with Java or Javascript, but i would like these informations.

Comment: OK, so did you try either of the provided solutions?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can use closest to find this out. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Add borders to the elements you want like so:

```
<p style="border: 1px solid black;">A paragraph</p>
```

Firefox has a neat trick to check elements.
Go to your page > Right click on it > Inspect element (a layout will appear at the bottom of the page). Top right of this layout in the gray area you have a 3d cube (it's the second item). Click on it and it will give you a 3d view of your page.